# How to Export database in specific folder's path in php?

Tags: php, database, location

We are Exporting our database from our site. But we want to download that database file automatically  in specific folder in our project folder. So how can we use code for location?

Comment: Do you mean that at specific time interval database file automatically downloaded to specific folder ?

Comment: You will do it using cron job set on your server.

Comment: We are succeeded in database downloading but we want to store that  downloaded file in specific folder.

Comment: share you php codes... need to set path...(?)

Comment: /*******EDIT LINES 3-8*******/
$DB_Server = "localhost"; //MySQL Server    
$DB_Username = "root"; //MySQL Username     
$DB_Password = "";             //MySQL Password     
$DB_DBName = "save";         //MySQL Database Name  
$DB_TBLName = "chat"; //MySQL Table Name
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$date=date('d-m-Y_H:i:a');   
$filename = "/home/saveyou/public_html/demo/$date";         //File Name
/*******YOU DO NOT NEED TO EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE*******/    
//create MySQL connection

Comment: $sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName";
$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
//select database   
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());   
//execute query 
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());    
$file_ending = "sql";
//header info for browser

Comment: header("Content-Type: application/sql");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.sql");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
}
print("\n");

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $schema_insert = "";
        for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
        {
            if(!isset($row[$j]))
                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
            elseif ($row[$j] != "")
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            else
                $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
        }

Comment: $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert .= "\t";
        print(trim($schema_insert));
        print "\n";
    }

Comment: @kiran Please put the code in question and format it properly and please provide details, also let everyone know where you stuck and what is exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure but You Can Try This,

```
$command='mysqldump --opt -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' > ~/' .$mysqlExportPath;
```